# This method must return a result of type int, java

Tags: java, return

I want to write a Programm which works rekursiv. It shall add two variables. But I am just allowed to add 1 or subtract 1. I made to .Java files. Each of them has one class.

Thats the main class:

```
  package rekursion;

    public class Main_function {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int a= 5;
            int b= 3;

            int result = rekursion.Addierer_Multiplizierer.add(a, b);

            System.out.print(result);
        }

    }
```

and that is the algorithm:

```
package rekursion;

public class Addierer_Multiplizierer {

    public static int add(int x, int y){      // here it Shows an error, 
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0){            // because the return value
            if(y==0){                 // is not of type int
                return x;       
            }
            return add(++x, --y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the compiler should warn you that there is "Missing return statement" at the end, a good IDE will tell you that, you should work with good tools

Comment: @azro... true, like IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 2):

Your method must have a return value in all of its execution branches.

The question is whether you are supposed to support negative inputs.

If not, you can change your method to:

```
public static int add(int x, int y)
{
    if(y == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return add(++x, --y);
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to check the sign of `y`, and decide whether to increment or decrement `y` in order to bring it to `0`:

```
public static int add(int x, int y) 
{
    if (y == 0) {
        return x;
    } else if (y > 0) {
        return add(++x, --y);
    } else {
        return add(--x, ++y);
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer a one liner:

```
public static int add(int x, int y) {
    return y == 0 ? x : y > 0 ? add(++x, --y) : add(--x, ++y);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me format that a bit for you to make it more clear...

```
 public static int add(int x, int y){ 
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0){
            if(y==0){
                return x;       
            }
            return add(++x, --y);
         }
         // ok, and what if not?
    }
```

Do you see the problem? Inside the first if-block you always return something... But what if `(x >= 0 && y >= 0)` is not true? No return for that. So you are missing something there.

Comment: No, I reformatted the code and added the comment to show the problem, since the formatting of the original code is the thing that made it hard to see...

Comment: It is the answer, but in a Socratic way which is not suitable for every reader.

You can edit it to say, your function does not return a value in _all_ cases.